# iterating through a list to append a value to variable lists

Tags: python, list, append, tuples, loops

I have the following data:

```
data = [['AB', 'BS, BT'], ['AH', 'AH'], ['AS', 'AS, GS']]
```

I would like to iterate through the lists of list to produce a list of tuples.

```
new_data = [('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', 'BT'), ('AH', 'AH'), ('AS', 'AS') ('AS', 'GS')]
```

I was thinking about using the zip() function, but wasn't sure if I was using the right logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` wouldn't be my first choice. My first choice would be `itertools.product` and `itertools.chain`

```
In [103]: data = [['AB', 'BS, BT'], ['AH', 'AH'], ['AS', 'AS, GS']]

In [104]: [list(itertools.product([d[0]], d[1].split(','))) for d in data]
Out[104]: [[('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT')], [('AH', 'AH')], [('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS')]]

In [105]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(itertools.product([d[0]], d[1].split(','))) for d in data]))
Out[105]: [('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT'), ('AH', 'AH'), ('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS')]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ``itertools.product`` is a nice way of doing this, +1. It's worth noting that in normal usage, you don't need the extra ``list()`` calls.

Comment: I can definitely see how the inner call is redundant. But wouldn't the outer `list` call be required?

Comment: If a list is strictly needed, yes, but 99% of the time an iterator does the job.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily enough with [`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). We use this to repeat the first item for each of the other items, which we get by splitting on `","`, then zipping up to generate our tuples. We then use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to generate a single list.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> data = [['AB', 'BS, BT'], ['AH', 'AH'], ['AS', 'AS, GS']]
>>> for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.repeat(first), second.split(",")) for first, second in data):
...     print(item)
... 
('AB', 'BS')
('AB', ' BT')
('AH', 'AH')
('AS', 'AS')
('AS', ' GS')
```

Answer (score 0):

using `zip()`:

```
In [32]: data
Out[32]: [['AB', 'BS, BT'], ['AH', 'AH'], ['AS', 'AS, GS']]

In [33]: [zip([x[0]]*len(x[1].split(",")),x[1].split(",")) for x in data]
Out[33]: [[('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT')], [('AH', 'AH')], [('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS')]]
```

use `chain()` to get the expected output:

```
In [34]: lis=[zip([x[0]]*len(x[1].split(",")),x[1].split(",")) for x in data]

In [35]: list(chain(*lis))
Out[35]: [('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT'), ('AH', 'AH'), ('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS')]
```

using `izip_longest`, with `fillvalue` equal to first element of each sublist:

```
In [47]: from itertools import chain,izip_longest

In [48]: lis=[tuple(izip_longest([x[0]],x[1].split(","),fillvalue=x[0])) for x in data]

In [49]: lis
Out[49]: [(('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT')), (('AH', 'AH'),), (('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS'))]

In [50]: list(chain(*lis))
Out[50]: [('AB', 'BS'), ('AB', ' BT'), ('AH', 'AH'), ('AS', 'AS'), ('AS', ' GS')]
```